# I am running into an issue trying to set a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, win32com

So simple functions work fine

```
 ws.Cells(2, 26).Formula = '=A4'
```

But trying to set a more complex formula:

```
 ws.Cells(2, 26).Formula = '=TEXT([@[Impact Restore Time]],"mmm-yy")'
```

This is giving an error:

```
 pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Any idea why it will not take this more complex formula? This works if I manually enter it.

Comment: A suggestion is to assign the formula to a string first and `print()` it. Then you can check it for syntax errors, or to see if any special characters have been transcribed. Also try the reverse: enter a complex formula in an Excel cell, then see what Python returns for the `.Formula` property.

Comment: I tried all those things.  It seems to be some kind of bug.  I actually got it to work once, and only once when manually running it in python shell. But I did find a work-a-round by formatting all the boxes as text boxes and doing a lookup and write (like the function would do if it worked).  It's not a formula, but fixed text so it's not idea, but it seems to work.

Comment: I can't say for sure since I cannot duplicate your sheet/formula however there is a good possibility the formula evaluated as invalid at the time it was entered in the sheet. I.e the formula references another value and you add the formula before the other reference is a [valid] value.  If its added latter/last it may work then.